# Is the orthogonal projection of y onto two orthogonal vectors the value of y?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality, projection

Is the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto two orthogonal vectors always simply $y$?

I am doing some self-guided study of linear algebra, and something in the course seemed to imply this was the case but I may have been misunderstanding. Is this true?

Comment: What do you mean by the "value" of $y$?

Comment: @Chrystomath I mean is the projection the same vector as y?

Comment: Of course not. If $y$ is orthogonal to $u,v$, then its projection is zero, right?

Comment: @Chrystomath right :) So it must have simply been the specific example being given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ if $ u $ and $ v $ are an orthogonal basis, then $ \mathrm{proj}_u{y} + \mathrm{proj}_v{y} = y $.  In general, if $ \{ u_n \} $ is an orthogonal *basis* for the space $ \mathbb{R}^n $ then an analogous statement holds, as I would encourage you to prove.